# screenSize in manifest and one part of layout

Tags: android

I have a problem with layout which is LinearLayout. I mean I have this line in manifest:  `android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|screenSize"`
and when I change orientation I have the same data. I have one RelativeLAyout in main layout which I don't want to still always the same, because when I change orientation my textViews missing. When I delete "screenSize" from manifest everything is ok with this RelativeLayout  but I loose other data. How can I set to RelativeLayout when I change orientation, my Relative layout change with orientation and behave like in manifest all class is without screenSize, but other part of main LinearLayout behave like screenSize was in manifest?

Answer (score 0):

create a new folder named `layout-land` and in it put your intended layout file

Comment: This solution doesn't help, because when change orientation I loose data.

Comment: you should use onSavedInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState, take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android